# Convert Flat Table list to Tree View

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tree, hierarchy

Can anyone help creating any dynamic table list to Tree View (Parent/Child) etc.

**Input :**

`TOTAL, NOT SPECIFIED     ALL CLASSES            NONE
    TOTAL, NOT SPECIFIED     WINTER                 NONE
    TOTAL, NOT SPECIFIED     SPRING, (EXCL DURUM)   NONE
    IRRIGATION METHOD        IRRIGATED              ALL CLASSES
    IRRIGATION STATUS        NON-IRRIGATED          ALL CLASSES`

**Expected Output :**

`NONE
        TOTAL, NOT SPECIFIED 
                             ALL CLASSES
                             WINTER
                             SPRING, (EXCL DURUM)
    ALL CLASSES
        IRRIGATED 
                 IRRIGATION METHOD
        NON-IRRIGATED
                 IRRIGATION STATUS`

So this all should be dynamic and it can recur itself up to any level.

On the other note I have this working alike but facing few bugs, Would appreciate if any javascript expert can make it flawless.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why do you put "Total, not specified" in the second level and not the third one? It looks like you pick your levels from right to left, but this is an exception

Comment: Is using an external library fine? With d3.js `nest` function, you can obtain things like this: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/ (see second example, it can be extended to any number of levels). Does that fit your needs?

Comment: Show us the bugs you're facing and what you've tried. Without a doubt, somebody will step in and write the code for you, but it'd probably help you more if you show *your* code and let us help you fix it...